# USB drive stops being (physically) readable on new Mac hardware but readable on old hardware under Linux

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I recently had the following situation:

- a USB penstick [formatted as a FileVault encrypted volume under MacOS] stopped being physically recognised by any of my Mac devices (a range of devices from an 8-year-old Mac Book Pro to a 2015 iMac to the latest 2020 M1 Mac Book Pro);
- I found that the penstick was physically recognised by a c. 8-year-old laptop running Linux (it obviously couldn't interpret the contents of the MacOS partition, but recognised the partition geometry and could physically read the contents, just not mount it);
- using sfdisk and dd, I was therefore able to make a verbatim copy on to a brand new penstick;
- that copy *was* then correctly recognised by my Mac devices.

In other words, to the old laptop running Linux, there was nothing physically wrong with the device, to the extent that it could read 100% of the contents, but multiple Macs did not even recognise the physical presence of the device, let alone report any logical corruption to the data.

So on the one hand: good news, I managed to recover the data... But on the other hand, I'd like to understand what might actually have happened here? Is there conceivably something physical that could have got damaged in a way that causes older hardware to be able to read the device but not newer hardware (the old Linux laptop is maybe c. 8-10 years old, whereas the oldest Mac in question is just under 8 years old).

Or equally, if it is likely to be an OS issue, has anyone had experience of a similar issue? When I say that Mac OS is unable to physically detect the device, I mean that there is no trace of it in "System Information" or disk manager. If there is a sneaky command line utility that would reveal it actually still being detected by the kernel under the hood, I'd also be interested to know.

Comment: I have a hypothesis but I need more data. What's the Model Identifier (like "MacBookProX,Y") on the 8 year old MBP? (You can get this from System Report inside "About this Mac")

Comment: Also, what's the make and model of the USB flash drive?

Comment: Thanks - all theories welcome! The 8 yo MBP is a "Retina, 15-inch Early 2013" model.  The Penstick is a 128GB Samsung that identifies itself as "Samsung Flash Drive FIT 1100" on the machine that can detect it. I also forgot to mention: I tried installing the same version of Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 4 and that couldn't detect the drive either.

Comment: Also tried it in a slightly later MBP (essentially similar model, but late 2013 I think), an iMac from c. 2016, a two year-old Mac Book and one of the new M1 Mac Book Pros, none of which detect the drive. The latter two were via a USB-C adapter. I wondered if one of the USB-C ports could have damaged the penstick in some subtle way that meant only the port on the very oldest machine could read it. If that's the case, it would be interesting to have an idea in order to avoid damaging other hardware in that same subtle way in the future... :)

Comment: Okay here's my hypothesis. Your flash drive is USB 3.x capable, and so are all your Macs. But 2012 is when Macs started supporting USB 3.x, and your even-older Linux laptop might be old enough to not support USB 3.x (at least not on all ports). USB 3.x added 5 new conductors to the connectors and cables. So if your flash drive got damaged on one of those USB 3.x-specific contact pads in the connector or internal circuit board traces, it might try to do USB 3 to a USB 3-capable host, but fail due to the damage. But in a USB 2 scenario with the Linux laptop, it won't try to use those conductors.

Comment: Is the penstick old enough to use jumpers for designating it as slave/master? (May need opening it up.) Or maybe it's a question of the driver.

Comment: .. And what exact model is the penstick?

Comment: @Spiff Thanks - your hypothesis checks out, I think. I've just re-tried the penstock in the raspberry pi, which has clearly identifiable USB 2 vs USB 3 ports, and it can be read in the USB2 ports but not the USB 3 ports. The old Acer laptop is probably old enough (and/or cheap enough) that it only had USB 2 ports. I'm slightly surprised that it isn't built into the standard that the USB 3 port would fall back on USB 2 in the even of this kind of situation, but there you go... P.S. If you want to write your hypothesis as an answer with the details, there's a few bounty points up for grabs :)

Answer (score 1):

Your flash drive is USB 3.x capable, which means it has the extra 5 conductors that USB 3 added to the USB connector. All your Macs are USB 3.x capable too, but your Linux laptop is just old enough that it might not be USB 3.x capable, at least not on all of its ports.

If your flash drive has damaged/failing pads, circuit board traces, or solder joints on those 5 new conductors specific to USB 3.x, that could explain it. It could be trying to work as a USB 3.x device on USB 3.x-capable machines, but failing due to the problem with the 5 new conductors. Whereas on a USB 2.x (or earlier) machine, it is only trying to do USB 2.x which just uses the original 4 conductors in the USB connector, so it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The poster has tried the penstick and verified that it only works on
USB 2.0 ports.
It doesn't work on USB 3.0 ports, so is probably a USB 2.0 device.

Although USB 3.0 ports are supposedly backward compatible with USB 2.0,
in practice many incompatibilities exist for unlucky pairs of
ports and flash drives.
Many posts exist on Google for such cases, and many were never explained.

There is even
[information](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000135207/usb-3-0-device-is-recognized-as-usb-2-0-on-a-dell-system)
that the speed with which a USB 2 device is inserted inside the port is
important, because the contacts specific to USB 3.0 are placed *behind*
the contacts for USB 2.0.
If you plug it in slowly, the USB 2.0 may get recognized before the
3.0 contacts are engaged.

We may never know the exact reason for incompatibility in your case,
but at least a solution was found.

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. The device is in principle a USB-3 device, but it's interesting to note the comment from Dell about it being "expected behaviour" for a USB-3 device to be recognised as USB-2 if plugged in slowly. (This sounds more of a bug than a feature, but something to bear in mind if something like this happens in the future :)

Comment: What happens if you plug the device in very quickly?

Answer (score 0):

This is trial-and-error, but it can work in case of slight physical damage:

insert your stick SLOWLY into the USB-port, with as least pressure as possible. Stop short before it's all inside. If it wiggles, try to wiggle slowly to the left & right. See if at a certain point the drive gets recognised.

What also might help is cleaning the contacts: start by blowing some air through the drive. Insert the tip of a paper cloth moist of some antistatic cleaning liquid (such as a screen cleaner).

Not all USB ports have the contacts in the exact same spot, so a different physical design might recognize a dirty or damaged stick, while others won't